# How can I check whether a document exists based on an optional field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am writing some Firestore rules to allow users to create posts and reply to each other. I have some rules to check whether a post is valid.

```
function isPost(data) {
  return data.keys().hasOnly(["title", "text", "parent")
    && data.title is string
    && data.get("text", "") is string
}
```

How can I add an **optional** "replyTo" field that would only be valid if it references an existing document (post) in the db?

I've tried this

```
function isPost(data) {
  return data.keys().hasOnly(["title", "text"])
    && data.title is string
    && data.get("text", "") is string
+   && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(data.get("replyTo", "")))
}
```

but it doesn't return a reference to a valid document, and therefore fails.

**EDIT**: Working solution based on @Dharmaraj's answer:

```
function isPost(data) {
  return data.keys().hasOnly(["title", "text", "replyTo"])
    && data.title is string
    && data.get("text", "") is string
    && (!('replyTo' in data) || exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(data.replyTo)))

}
```

Comment: I removed the Javascript tag because the security rules language is [something else](https://github.com/google/cel-spec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `replyTo` field is a reference then it's value would be `posts/postId` so you don't need collection name in path:

```js
// remove /posts from this
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(data.replyTo))
```

The following rule will pass if `replyTo` field is missing or will ensure the document referenced exists in case it does:

```
allow read: if !('replyTo' in data) || exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(data.replyTo))
```

Comment: I would like the request to succeed if there is no `data.replyTo`, as it is an optional field. Your reply would make it so that the request fails if there is no `data.replyTo` defined.

Comment: @styke can you check the updated answer and let me know if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Indeed it does! Your answer uses a redundant `exists` but is otherwise perfect. I am updating the OP with the solution. Thank you!